# How to return value from Viewpager : OnPageSelected?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I need the selected position of viewpager but to do that i should create inner class like this.

```
ViewPager Karosel = findViewById(R.id.karosel);

Karosel.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                int asiap = position+1;
            //this is the value what i want
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
//and the value is used for this void
loadTribesName(number[0], name, subnumber[0],region);
```

i've tried to put loadTribesName in onPageSelected like this

```
Karosel.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                int asiap = position+1;

loadTribesName(number[0], name, asiap,region);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

loadTribesName(number[0], name, subnumber[0],region);
```

but my viewpager is blinking and overwrite each other and while i try to swipe it, makes the activity finish itself.

I already tried Karosel.getCurrentItem(); but it doesn't work

is there a way to get the value "asiap" out of the class, or some other way?

Comment: what loadTribesName does?

Comment: it shows fragment datas

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the values using **Interface** from activity to fragment and also while changing the fragment. so i would suggest to use interface between activity and fragment.

just create one interface and register it while loading fragment and assign that to each fragment and while changing fragment you will get callback.